# SQL Azure Reset autoincrement

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I found a lot of topics telling to use :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 0)
```

But this is not supported by Azure SQL. Does somebody have any idea on how to do it easily ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset identity seed in Sql Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415434/how-to-reset-identity-seed-in-sql-azure)

Answer (score 6):

DBCC CHECKIDENT is [not supported for now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336253.aspx) in SQL Azure as you commented.

[Check this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/ceeae474-fb19-4282-a56b-c0718f06e9ab), there are some solutions proposals, maybe one of them can help you out.

Comment: The `set identity_insert … on|off` statements helped me out just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't have too many options... the only one I can think of is to drop and recreate your table.