# Which query is used to reseed identity primary key in sql server 2012 since DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 1) not working in 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The below query is executed successfully in sql server 2008 R2 for reseeding identity key

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 1)
```

But gives error in sql server 2012 as:

> Msg 40518, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   DBCC command 'CHECKIDENT' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 superceded IDENTITY with ANSI standard SEQUENCEs, so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx

Comment: You using SQL Server 2012 Management studio (Maybe some beta version)? Because this should work

Comment: It sure *looks* like it's still [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c00ee51-2062-4e47-8b19-d90f524c6427)

Comment: I suspect he's using SQL Azure, which [doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336253.aspx) `CHECKIDENT`. If so, someone has asked this question [already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415434/how-to-reset-identity-seed-in-sql-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to reseed and empty the table?? Is so, a simple table truncation with work. Truncating the table with both empty the table and re-seed the identity field.

Comment: as I said, if you are wanting to empty the table out and re-seed, do this:

TRUNCATE TableName;

Comment: Don't think this is a good thing for re-seeding, since there are other options. TRUNCATE will delete ALL your data in the table, quite aggressive for only a reseed action...

Comment: i did say in my comments that this method will empty out the table... was trying to give him a quick and easy solution....