# Trying to reset Identity value for SQL Azure DB Table column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Azure. I have a deployment DB and a test DB

I would like to add some new lookup records to the Test DB, to test new code.

Initially My Deployment DB's Identity was set to 200000+ for the PKs, and my Test DB to 100000+, to prevent PK collisions when syncing using such tools as Redgates' SQL data compare.

Unfortunately I made a mistake, and copied the Deployment DB as the new Test DB, since we required a more up to date dataset. As a result my Test DB now starts at 200000+. So I now have the risk of conflicts when syncing with the Deployment DB.

I would normallly just use:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 105000)
```

However SQL Azure does not support this.

I have come across a workaround:

```
set identity_insert TableName on  -- this basically turns off IDENTITY

INSERT INTO TableName(id, name) VALUES (104999,'Test Reset Identity Start 104999')   -- so we can jam any value for column ID

set identity_insert TableName off  -- then turn it back on

INSERT INTO TableName(name) VALUES ('Test Reset Identity End') -- ID starts at 105000, in theory, from this point

SELECT * FROM TableName
```

However the new Identify value always seems to take the highest PK in the table as the last seed, rather than the PK value from the last inserted record.

I would rather not rebuild the table.

Is there another approach to resetting the identity value for my situation, ie to a lesser number ie 104999 rather the current 204999?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

It may be I can only check the identity value to a value greater than the current value ie to say 206000 ?

EDIT 2

Perhaps there is an argument that Identity value should never be reseed to less than the max PK value, even if there is 100,000 spare numbers, as one day you will get a collision.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415434/how-to-reset-identity-seed-in-sql-azure

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had spotted this post. The end result is a number on and above the current maxid. I was exploring how to reseed to a lower number ie around 100000+, where the maxid is currently 200000+, assuming there was a gap of number of 50000 to 100000 from 100000 to the current 200000