# How do I set an Identity Seed on an Azure database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I need to demo an ASP.Net MVC application for a client, and due to problems with the expected hosting providers I am trying to host it on Azure as a temporary solution. Best to point out here my experience of Azure is approximately four hours...a complete noob.

The original - and eventual - target database is SQL Server, and the databases are created using Entity Framework Code First. I was using DBCC CHECKIDENT to set the seed value for some identity columns, and then seeding the data, all in the database initializer.

Azure does not recognize DBCC CHECKIDENT, and having a look around this is a known issue. I've looked at some solutions, but they involve migrating existing data, which is not what I need here, in the code I set the seed, then load the test data.

Is there a simple method to do this?

EDIT: Updated the Azure DB to V12, which has stopped the DBCC errors. 
I am now getting timeouts occuring, which I am not sure is before it gets to the DBCC part.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415434/how-to-reset-identity-seed-in-sql-azure

Comment: FWIW, and in the interest of simplicity, you may consider spinning a VM up (Go IaaS route) and loading SQL express. Don't know what your time frame is for delivery, but sometimes it's best to get it out the door.

Comment: Not even got as far as VM's yet, I'm a complete noob with Azure.
I was publishing the site through Visual Studio, which created the tables fine,  fell over on this DBCC thing. Looking at the link above, I'm not sure if it created V12 or not...looking into that now.

Comment: Not sure if the old portal has the ability to update to v12.  You can do it directly in the new portal with a few clicks.  By new portal, I mean https://portal.azure.com.  As far as resolving your issue, I can't be much help.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I was using the old one :)